# iPhone or Android App, not for Google or Apple Store

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

what does someone do, who just write an application for more device and does not want to go on the market Google Play Store or Apple App Store?

Comment: Do you want to sell it outside of the market's, install it in an enterprise environment, or just play around with the tech?

Comment: no i want use it in my company, also Yes install it in an enterprise environment.

Comment: for apple, you can distribute apps internally (enterprise) with a US$ 299 enterprise developer license.  that costs money, but then you don't have to pay Apple for each user or make the application public (App Store), nor do users have to jailbreak their devices.  this is also called "Ad Hoc" distribution by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve. In general, you are mostly limited by the amount of people using these alternative stores and that it's in some cases significantly harder to actually get them installed.

For Apple:

- You can publish in [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/) store for jailbroken iOS devices

For Android, there are a number of alternative markets, e.g.: http://www.howtogeek.com/106175/the-top-5-alternatives-to-the-android-market/

Answer (score 1):

For Android, all you need is the Android SDK, Eclipse, and the ADT plugin. You don't need to go near the Play Store/Market to make a full Android app.

As for iOS, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For **Android** simply write the app and [distribute the `APK` via email internally](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/install-apk-files-on-android/) in your Enterprise. As for **Apple** looks like you have to go with their [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For android you can post your apps on PlayMarket or on Amazone app store. Or you can just create your apk file with eclipse and post it anywhere in internet with no profit to yourself(or earn money by adds).

You can't get ios app on iPhone not from apple Appstore, unless you are just testing your app on real device (which costs 99$ month and is part of full developer account).

Answer (score -1):

That one could run his apps on simulator, or on his own device. He could also run his apps on someone else's device, it's enough to add his device and share your provisioning profile with him. But be aware:

> Important: Your iOS Developer Program membership can be terminated if
>   you provide pre-release Apple Software to anyone other than employees,
>   contractors, and members of your organization who are registered as
>   Apple Developers and have a demonstrable need to know or use Apple
>   Software in order to develop and test applications on your behalf.
>   Unauthorized distribution of Apple Confidential Information (including
>   pre-release Apple Software) is prohibited and may subject you to both
>   civil and criminal liability.